# Table header with rounded corners and border

Tags: css, border, rounded-corners

Is it possible for a table header to have rounded corners **and** a 1px border?

When I apply a border to the `th` elements, the border corners are square instead of round.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid;
}

th:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

th:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
  <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My solution is to add span or div in my cells.

Comment: please add relevant markup, maybe it doesn't work with tables or maybe your mark has a mistake

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Answer (score 4):

This makes **all** table headers (if you are using semantic `th` cells instead of body `td` cells) have rounded corners, but if you wish it for only selected tables - then rename the class to `table.rounded th` and just add `rounded` class to those tables:

```
th { 
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

**EDIT:** you need to have `border-collapse: separate;` on your table for this to be possible...

Comment: This is pretty much what I have right now, and it's creating square border corners...

Comment: @user1438243 your table itself must not have any borders, and check in browser developer tools if this is getting applied in the computed styles (maybe something is overriding it)? and a jsfiddle would be a must... oh, and does your browser actually support rounded tables?

Comment: @user1438243 check the edit, it was presumed - but you probably missed that

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<div>` wrapper inside of each `<th>`. Add your border styles to the wrappers.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  padding: 0;
}

th div {
  background: cyan;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 80px;
}

th:first-child div {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

th:last-child div {
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><div>Col 1</div></th>
    <th><div>Col 2</div></th>
    <th><div>Col 3</div></th>
    <th><div>Col 4</div></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That would probably work, I'm just looking for the most straightforward and least hacky way of doing it. Ideally with no additional HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-shadow` to fake the border:

```css
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #ddd inset;
```

Admittedly, this results in a brighter color than with normal borders, so you'll have to compensate for that.